# Spring MVC annotation config problem

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I'm trying to improve my spring mvc configuration so as to not require a new config file for every servlet I add, but I'm running into problems. I've tried using [this tutorial](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/21/mvc-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) as a starting point, but I'm running into an issue that I can't figure out.

The problem is that when I do a GET to my servlet, I get back a 404 error. Here's my config and a representative java snippet from a Controller:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>SightLogix Coordination System</display-name>

    <description>SightLogix Coordination System</description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>     
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>
                    /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
                    /WEB-INF/application-security.xml
                </param-value>
            </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/slcs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/application-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"

    default-init-method="init" default-destroy-method="destroy">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="top.level" />
</beans>
```

application-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_MANAGER" requires-channel="https" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="sha"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService"
        class="path.to.my.UserDetailsServiceImpl">
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Snippet of a Controller class (one of many, but they all look essentially like this):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo.xml")
public class FooController
{       
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void handleGET(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        ...
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using /slcs/foo.xml as the URL with HTTPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing out of place here is that you've used the same context config files for both the root webapp context *and* your servlet context. This is almost guaranteed to be a bad idea, and will result in a lot of weird behaviour. This may well be the cause of your problem.

The `ContextLoaderListener` is configured with the `contextConfigLocation` `<context-param>`, and creates and manages the root `WebApplicationContext`.

The `ServletDispatcherServlet` is configured with the `contextConfigLocation` `<init-param>`, and creates and manages the servlet `WebApplicationContext`.

The root `WebApplicationContext` is the parent of the servlet appcontext, i.e any beans in the root `WebApplicationContext` are visible to those beans in the servlet `WebApplicationContext`.

Your first step should be to separate those configurations. With the correct beans in the correct places (e.g. all MVC stuff has to go in the servlet context). Do *not* share bean definitions between the two, it'll just get confusing and/or broken.

Comment: With that sort of configuration, the servlet init param should point to an empty bean definition file - the context loader listener is going to load all the beans, then they'll all be overridden by themselves when the dispatcher servlet loads.  While I agree with you in principle with separating out the MVC stuff into the servlet's specific configuration files, in this case there's only one servlet so this isn't really needed - it's when two or more servlets pop up that separation becomes more important.

Comment: I separated out the context files for my application and my servlets, but I'm still getting that 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but I've always found it helpful to enable debug logging in Spring when I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Below are two that I commonly use in my logging.properties file:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.level=FINEST
org.springframework.security.level=FINEST
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one `GET RequestMapping` in your controller by any chance? If there are more than one and there is ambiguity in resolving them to a particular request Spring does not map to any of the ambiguous GET mappings.